# What is the difference between inline and constexpr captureless lambda in a header?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, inline, constexpr

If I declare a captureless lambda in a header, what is the difference between

```
inline auto myLambda = []() { ... };
```

and

```
constexpr auto myLambda = []() { ... };
```

If I understand correctly, `constexpr` imply inline, and lambdas are constexpr by default. So I'm not even sure that I need the `inline` or `constexpr` keyword.

What I want to avoid by declaring `myLambda` inline is One Definition Rule (ODR) violations, since this variable with be visible in multiple translation units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, `constexpr` imply inline, and lambdas are `constexpr` by default.

The first part is true, but not for this case. From [[dcl.constexpr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-3):

> A function or static data member declared with the `constexpr` or `consteval` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline]).

In our case, we don't have either a function or a static data member, so it's not implicitly inline. You'd have to explicitly mark it as such.

The second part isn't *quite* right. From [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-4.sentence-5):

> The function call operator or any given operator template specialization is a constexpr function if either the corresponding *lambda-expression*'s *parameter-declaration-clause* is followed by `constexpr` or `consteval`, or it satisfies the requirements for a constexpr function ([dcl.constexpr]).

The *call operator* is `constexpr` by default, but the lambda *itself* is not. Which for a capture-less lambda is basically fine, you can still use the call operator - as demonstrated in the example for this section:

> ```
> auto ID = [](auto a) { return a; };
> static_assert(ID(3) == 3);                      // OK
> ```

In short, if you're declaring this lambda in the header, you definitely need the `inline` keyword and it doesn't hurt to just slap on the `constexpr` keyword either.